# Integration of OMNeT++ and SUMO through VEINS

Tags: omnet++

I made a scenario in SUMO and also have a runner.py file in order to control the traffic in sumo.
When I use a normal scenario without runner fil, everything is ok but I need to get the movement after using runner file.
Do you know how Can I get the output after using this runner file in omnet++. When I call the runner.py file it opens the sumo and I can see the movement but when I link sumo and omnet++, since this file is not called, therefore, I cannot get the real movement in omnet++.
And how can i see both Omnet++ simulation and sumo-gui dialog box at a time ? 
could someone help me out with this !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SUMO currently has no feature that supports controlling a running instance of SUMO from two programs. In your case, both OMNeT++ and your runner.py would try to control, e.g., how fast the simulation runs.

The easiest solution would be to move functionality from your runner.py into a new OMNeT++ module that uses Veins' modules to influence the simulation.